# Datatables Editor node.js - Custom file validator - Get height and with of img file

Tags: javascript, node.js, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm using datatables editor with node.js. I need a customer file validator: https://editor.datatables.net/manual/nodejs/upload#Custom-validation

Is there a way to get height and width of a uploaded img file? I want to validate height x width geometric.

```
.validator(
    Validate.fileExtensions(
         ['png', 'jpg'],
         'Only image files can be uploaded (png and jpg)'
    )
 )
 .validator( file => {
      console.log('file:');
      console.log(file);
 
      return true;
   })
```

console:

```
{ uuid: 'fsdfe20sdfsdf1',
field: 'upload',
file:
'/tmp/express-busboy/fsdfe20sdfsdf1/upload/logo.jpg',
filename: 'logo.jpg',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
truncated: 'false',
done: 'true',
size: 16453,
extn: 'jpg',
name: 'logo' }
```

Comment: What about using - https://github.com/image-size/image-size